# How to remove Leaflet.markercluster animation when spiderfy a cluster

Tags: leaflet

I need to remove the animation when someone clicks on a cluster.
I would like to remove the line drawing in particular.

An example can be found here: http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.388.html

To see the spiderfy click on those cluster in sequence: 239, 18 (on top left), 10

Answer (score 0):

What if you edit leaflet.markercluster-src.js in **line 17** from
    **spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true**
to 
    **spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false**

Comment: You wrote the same thing twice. Probably you mean 'spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false'. I want the 'spiderfyOnMaxZoom' but without animation. I'll take a look on the source code asap I've a little time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same thing: a way to spiderfy but without the SVG animation (it is throwing some anoying message to the browser console at the moment).

What I did was to add "continue" on the lines 1939 (animation starts) and then in the line 2025 (animation  ends). And that worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way how to completely remove the lines but you hide them with **spiderLegPolylineOptions**.

Try:

```
L.markerClusterGroup({
   spiderLegPolylineOptions: {opacity: 0}
});
```